# Plot directional edges as non-overlapping lines

Tags: python, networkx, mode-analytics

I have a networkx directional graph.  I'd like to plot it so that nodes that interact (A->B, B->A) have two edges displayed and the colors correspond to the relative weights.

Currently I have a simple three-node graph.  Naturally the flow is "order created" -> "order closed" but on not-so-rare occasions the flow can be reversed!

[image: my simple graph]

Since this is going on a dashboard, I need to avoid the "download it and use another software package" to visualize it.  Ideally I'd just use igraph (love it in R), but it's not supported in my environment (Mode Analytics).

Is the best solution to just create a hack where I split every node to a pair: "node-sender" and "node-receiver"?  At least that would have the bonus of seeing self-edges too.  Or maybe switch to plotly's chord diagram?

**Edit: What I'm looking for**

Ideally I could just use something like the qgraph package in R.

```
edges <- data.frame(from = from_node, to = to_node, thickness = weights)
qgraph(edges, esize=10, gray=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having difficulty telling what you're asking. Can you provide an example of what you'd like to see?

Comment: I really like the R package qgraph: easy to use, good visualization.

Comment: I wrote a little package for this purpose some time when I had the same problem and found out that you simply cannot do what you are suggesting in networkx: https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph. API is very similar to networkx.

Comment: Love it!  Sadly, not supported by Mode yet though.